# How to make sense of the word 'as' in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

"*It stands to be the only truly international journal that focuses on vocational learning, **as** encompassing the activities that comprise vocational education and professional education in their diverse forms internationally.*"

Is the clause 'as encompassing the activities...' in this sentence used to explain this journal? Or is it used to explain vocational learning?

Comment: @Joachim: I've tidied it up a bit and am trying to do an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be from [Scimago Journal & Country Rank](https://www.scimagojr.com/journalsearch.php?q=15700154701&tip=sid).

It seems to say,

> The journal will become ('stands to be') the only truly international
> one that focuses on vocational learning and the way it (vocational
> learning) encompasses the activities of both vocational and
> professional education in their diverse forms internationally.

If 'learning' and 'education' are the same thing, it boils down to...

> The journal will become the only truly international one that focuses
> on vocational learning and the way it encompasses vocational and
> professional learning in their diverse forms internationally.

To say vocational learning encompasses vocational learning seems barely worthwhile. But perhaps there is a difference between education and learning.

If the writer had wanted us to understand it I think they would have written it differently.

Comment: +1 "barely worthwhile" pretty much sums it up.

Comment: @TimR :-) Thanks! It must be so dispiriting to come across a sentence like that when you're trying to learn English!

Answer (score 0):

The sentence would certainly make sense if "as" were a subordinating conjunction introducing a finite clause:

> It stands to be the only truly international journal that focuses on vocational learning, as it encompasses the activities that comprise vocational education and professional education in their diverse forms internationally.

The situation is more unusual when "as" is followed by a present participle phrase. We could understand this as an elliptical clause with two words omitted:

> It stands to be the only truly international journal that focuses on vocational learning, as [[it is]] encompassing the activities that comprise vocational education and professional education in their diverse forms internationally.

The progressive aspect seems out-of-place with those two words included, but that issue is largely irrelevant when they are omitted.

An alternative is to consider the present participle phrase as a direct modifier of its antecedent. In that case, "as" would modify the present participle phrase. This use of "as" is defined in M-W as:

> when considered in a specified form or relation —> usually used before a preposition or a participle
> | my opinion *as* distinguished from his